# how do i insert a line at the start of the table in SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to insert a record at the start of my table in Android . How do I do it? I know `insert` query inserts at the end of the table . I am currently using it like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase writableDb;
long rowID = writableDb.insert(tableName, null, ContentValues);
```

I also do not want to use the `ORDER BY` option .

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: `"I also do not want to use the ORDER BY option ."` so you have to change your mind and use it

Comment: @pskink  hmmm . Ok. So there is no other option .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no other option than using ORDER BY . I am using ORDER BY now